# Get file name in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a input file which takes multiple files and the tag is given the Id = fileToUpload
and here goes the code:

```
var input = document.getElementById('filesToUpload');
for (var x = 0; x < input.files.length; x++) {
    oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(input.files[x]);
    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
         imageSrc = oFREvent.target.result;
         console.log("source:" +imageSrc);
         name = oFREvent.target.name;
         console.log("name:" +name);
     };
}
```

Here I am able to get the source of the image but I am not able to get the name of the file which is selected for uploading. I am doing the right way or this is not a right way to get a file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the name from the original [filelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList), not the target of the FileReader's onload event. The [`FileReader` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) doesn't have a `name` property and the target of the `onload` event is the FileReader, not the file.

**EDIT**

Getting the name file loaded into the FileReader turns out to be kinda tricky! I came up with two ways which you [**can see in this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7JTpL/).

First way just seems plain wrong - add a `name` property to your new FileReader() instance and then access it via `evt.target`. Works in FF and Chrome anyway.

```
var input = document.getElementById('filesToUpload');
    input.addEventListener("change", soWrongButItSeemsToWork, false);

function soWrongButItSeemsToWork () {
    var filelist = this.files;

    for (var x = 0; x < filelist.length; x++) {
        oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.name = filelist[x].name;
        console.log("name outside:", oFReader.name);
        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent ) {
            imageSrc = oFREvent.target.result;
            console.log('name inside:', oFREvent.target.name);
            img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = imageSrc;
            document.body.appendChild(img);
         };

        oFReader.readAsDataURL(filelist[x]);

    }
}
```

Use a closure as suggested by http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html (at the bottom). Something like:

```
var input2 = document.getElementById('fileinput');
    input2.addEventListener("change", readMultipleFiles, false);

function readMultipleFiles(evt) {
    //Retrieve all the files from the FileList object
    var files = evt.target.files; 

    if (files) {
        for (var i=0, f; f=files[i]; i++) {
            var r = new FileReader();
            r.onload = (function(f) {

                return function(e) { // WOOHOO!
                  var dataUri = e.target.result,
                      img     = document.createElement("img");

                      img.src = dataUri;
                      document.body.appendChild(img);

                      console.log( "Got the file.n" 
                          +"name: " + f.name + "\n"
                          +"type: " + f.type + "\n"
                          +"size: " + f.size + " bytes\n"

                    ); 
                };
            })(f);

            r.readAsDataURL(f);
        }   
    } else {
          alert("Failed to load files"); 
    }
}
```

Good article on MDN here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: Yeah this I tried if I try to print the name inside the `oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) { console.log("name:", name); }` then I am getting only the last filename instead of the particular file name. \n For example I have 3 files 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg then 3.jpg is getting printed three times in place of other file names.

Comment: @user2823355 gotcha. Updated by answer with new code and a fiddle.

Comment: The second solution you have given works fine I guess but I havent tried it as I was not in the senario of defining an **EventListener**

Comment: @user2823355 huh? `oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent){}` is defining an event listener. "Listen for the `onload` event on the `oFReader` instance of the `FileReader` object and execute this anonymous function." Maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code work perfectly:**

```
var input = document.getElementById('filesToUpload');
for (var x = 0; x < input.files.length; x++) {
    oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(input.files[x]);
    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
         imageSrc = oFREvent.target.result;
         console.log("source:" +imageSrc);
         name = imageSrc.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
         console.log("name:" +name);
     };
}
```

Comment: No this is not working on what basis are you trying to get get file name from **imageSource** here when we don't have image name in the imageSource.

Comment: what you get from imageSrc? url or any other.

Comment: please print sample for imageSrc

Answer (score 0):

I have did a work around for this and here is the example given:

```
var input = document.getElementById('filesToUpload');
for (var x = 0; x < input.files.length; x++) {
oFReader = new FileReader();
oFReader.readAsDataURL(input.files[x]);
var index = 0;
oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
     imageSrc = oFREvent.target.result;
     console.log("source:" +imageSrc);
     //name = oFREvent.target.name;
     name = input.files[index++].name;
     console.log("name:" +name);
 };
```

}

Each time I iterate over the reader object then I increment the index so that it indexs to the next fine in the array.